# Matlab interpolating a 2D function

Tags: interpolation, numerical-methods

I have a grid of uniform points sampling some unknown function. I want to estimate the gradient of this function at any point on the domain.

I am using an iterative algorithm that estimates the derivatives at different points of the domain at each step. E.g. I might have

```
 A = randi(5,[5,5]); % some discrete representation of a function

 [x1, x2] = gradient(A); % with some appropriate step sizes
```

If for example the domain is [0,1]^2, is there a nice way to evaluate the coordinates in the gradient space if I pick any real coordinates in the unit square?

I have looked at Matlab's griddata but it seems to construct uniform grids, whereas the points I wish to evaluate are not. Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/6997/interpolation-with-matlab#t=201609240756562856801

Comment: For `interp2` you don't need uniform grids. Hope this does help.

Comment: @StefanM thanks I actually used griddedInterpolant in the end - that did the job perfectly. Free free to add that as an answer :)